# getTitle() is not displayed the correct output in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

In the following program; getTitle() returns wrong o/P:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
      "E:\\Technologies\\Automation-Selenium\\Selenium Files\\geckodriver.exe");

   System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",
      "E:\\Technologies\\Automation-Selenium\\Selenium Files\\IEDriverServer.exe");

   WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

   driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");

   String title = driver.getTitle();

   System.out.println(title);
}
```

Output in Eclipse:
**WebDriver**
(Why not Google ?)

Answer (score 1):

This happens with `IEdriver`; because whenever `IEDriver` is launched first it opens following screen with "WebDriver" title :

[image]

so you just need to wait a few more seconds before it navigates to actual URL, for example in your case `www.google.com`.

Comment: Yes, it is correct, it only happens in IEdriver, but wait is also not working here.

Comment: try following: `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
  
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("google.com"));`

Answer (score 0):

Normally equals doesn't work well with strings. 
Can you use `if(title.equalsIgnoreCase("Google"))` It would solve your purpose!

Comment: It is also showing the same Output. Btw Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

At last, I got the correct answer. We need to set same Security level in all zones. To do that follow the steps below:

1. Open IE
2. Go to Tools -> Internet Options -> Security
3. Set all zones to the same protected mode, enabled or disabled should not matter.
4. Finally, set Zoom level to 100%